# Problems playing two raw files at the same time through two MediaPlayers

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, ringtone

I'm developing a Voip-Application and i have an edge case where i want to play two raw files at the same time.

When i have an incoming call from my application i am creating a new Mediaplayer and play a custom ringtone. When i get shortly after also  an incoming GSM-call i create a new mediaplayer and play a knocking sound to give the user feedback that there is also a GSM-Call incoming. At the same time i want the custom ringtone to continue playing.

```
private fun setAudioAttributesForFile(audioUsage: Int): AudioAttributes {
    return AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(audioUsage)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .build()
}

private fun startRingtone(fileToPlay: Int): MediaPlayer {
    return MediaPlayer().apply {
        reset()
        if (fileToPlay == R.raw.ring {
            setAudioAttributes(setAudioAttributesForFile(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE))
        } else {
            setAudioAttributes(setAudioAttributesForFile(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA))
        }
        isLooping = true
        Main.get().resources.openRawResourceFd(fileToPlay).use {
            setDataSource(
                    it.fileDescriptor,
                    it.startOffset,
                    it.length
            )
        }
        setOnPreparedListener { start() }
        prepareAsync()
    }
}
```

The problem that i have with this code is that as soon as the knocking sound is playing the ringtone gets muted by the system and as soon as the knocking sound is stopping the ringtone continues.

What i also tried:

1. Using only
   `AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE`. As soon as the knocking sound starts to play both mediaPlayers are getting muted.
2. If i leave the `setAudioAttributes()` call away and replace these four lines to

```
if (fileToPlay == R.raw.ring) {
    setAudioAttributesForFile(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE)
} else {
    setAudioAttributesForFile(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
}
```

then i can play those two files at the same time. The problem then is that the ringtone file is not shown as a ringtone instead it is only shown as a media file. So when i increase and decrease the volume of the ringtone the flag does not show that it is a ringtone.

Is there a way to play one sound as a Ringtone and another sound over it as a normal Media Sound?

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use sound pool if you want to play both sounds at the same time.

Comment: Hey Ajay, i edited my post. I am already able to play both sounds at the same time. The problem is actually slightly different.

Comment: Is it play the default rigton when you got the notification?

Comment: It is not playing the default ringtone but that is simply because i want to play a custom ringtone. 
I will have a look into the ringtone Manager. Thanks!